# Products not showing in parent categories

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, category

I want products that are in a sub category to appear in the parent category page on the front end also.

So all `parent/child` products appear in `parent`.

All questions relating to this say to make sure `anchor` is set to `on` in the category settings.  All my categories have anchor enabled but only products explicitly set for the parent categories appear there, none of the child categories products appear in the parents category page on the front end.

I have re-indexed and cleared cache.  Is there a setting I am missing?

If I add the parent category tag to the product then it appears in parent category but I want to be able to tag the product with child category and then the product also appears in all the parent categories.